# Tar - exclude all files in sub folder but not nested folders

Tags: tar, archive

I need to create a .tgz archive of the following folder

```
pack
  |
  rest
    |
    vendor (folder)
    |
    ----index.php
    |
    ----info.log
    | 
    another (folder)
    |
    ---index.php
    |
    ---info.log
    |
    ---somefile.someext 
   |
   somefolder1
   |
   somefoldern
   |
   somefiles.somexts
```

Just issuing an `exclude=index.php` etc has unwanted consequences: **vendor** might in turn have a file bearing that name directly or in one of its sub folders. I haven't been able to establish from the documentation whether I can instruct tar to ignore all file contents in the rest folder but NOT the sub folders under it.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of those running into this post here is the solution that works - at least on Ubuntu 14.04.  For the folders structure I have shown above issue

```
tar -zcf pack.tgz --exclude-from=/path/to/excludes.list pack
```

*excludes.list* contains, in my case

```
rest/index.php
rest/info.log
rest/filetoexclude.ext
```

...essentially a list of files to exclude.  Points to note

- Using an absolute path to excludes.list file makes it easier to compose the command to build the archive via a shell command executed in a scripting language.
- The excluded files are in the form `folder/file.ext`, **relative** to the folder being archived.
- There should be a newline char immediately after each filename entry. In a text editor it is easy to get a space in just after the filename in which case it will not get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "`another/index.php`" as the pattern (or even "`rest/another/index.php`"):

```
$ mkdir -p pack/rest/vendor
$ mkdir -p pack/rest/another
$ touch pack/rest/{vendor,another}/index.php
$ tar --create --verbose --file  xx.tar --exclude "another/index.php"  pack/
pack/
pack/rest/
pack/rest/another/
pack/rest/vendor/
pack/rest/vendor/index.php
```

I found that for more complex selections of tar file contents it is easier to use `find` with pruning, and, or, etc., and until you can generate the exact list of input. And then pipe that into `cpio` and its `--format=ustar` output mode to generate a tar file.

Comment: Not sure on which distro you tried this.  On Ubuntu 14.04 I find two issues - firstly the exclude switch does nothing unless it is followed by an = sign. Secondly - with the = - the exclusiion is applied to the parent directory and its child folders which is not what I want.

Comment: @DroidOS This was copy and pasted from a Linux Mint 17 session. The only thing I noticed is that there was an extra return inserted during pasting on the `tar` line so that the final argument `pack` was not on the correct line. I tried it once more, without problems or `=` and verified the `xx.tar`. `tar --version` gives: tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1

Comment: Thanks. On Ubuntu 14.04, no = causes the exclude switch to be simply ignored.  However, I have found that `--exclude-from=excludesfilelist` works as expected.  I'll put that  in an answer in a minute